# Code I didn't write appears to be using an undeclared variable in SQL fetch

Tags: php, sql, variables, select

So I am looking through someone elses code and can't for the life of me figure out how this is working.  It appears this line:

```
$rs = $db->Execute("select web_data from Table_1 where title_name='$name'");
```

where $db is this:

```
$db = new COM("ADODB.Connection"); 
$dsn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=$myserver;Database=$mydb;Uid=$myid;Pwd=$mypass";
$db->Open($dsn);
```

is using $name but it is NOT declared ANYWHERE.  The value its passing is coming from ?name=value on the query string.  Is there some reason this should be working or do I have to be missing something?  So confused....

Comment: It does work if register_globals (in php.ini) is On. It shouldn't be on. It can ruin anything, literally anything.

Comment: The register_globals option is enabled. See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php (Example #3).

Comment: Bad idea. To start with define `$name = $_GET['name'];`, then throw it out and use parameterised queries or at least some form of data sanitization.

Comment: OMG REALLY?!  This dude is killing me.  What about this in php.ini..."register_argc_argv"

Comment: Anyways register_globals is definitely turned on and appears to be the case.  Thanks for the help!!